Path to pin driver to action on bones
i have bones with actions. When i use that actions i wanna change value some drivers on other object. How can i do that? i weak in python(


Can you be more explicit about what you expect, if things were working perfectly? Please describe, from the bottom up, what  you want to happen.

I have human bones that have action (dope sheet). And also there is a person's hairstyle, which has morphs (shape keys). It is necessary that when applying any specific animation on the bone at the shape key of the mannequin's hairstyle, the driver is turned on.
